# GridView no column present even after DataBind()

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a DataView that was already populated with data (Verified this to be true).

I then set the DataSource of my GridView to that DataView and called the .DataBind() Function.

Right after binding, I checked the column count of my GridView (grid.Columns.Count) and it shows 0. But it is showing the right output with 15 columns.

Also, accessing a column using its index will throw an exception.

How can I access the column then?

Thanks!

EDIT -- Additional Info:

I actually need to add a "glyph" (UP/DOWN arrow) in the column header to show what column are being sorted and its direction. The code below is what I am using. Problem is, the Columns.Count is always zero.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dgData.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string colExpr = dgData.Columns[i].SortExpression;
        if (colExpr != "" && colExpr == dgData.SortExpression)
            item.Cells[i].Controls.Add(glyph);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Try this, it's a little fugly as it relies on testing the linkbutton text against the GridView SortExpression. The Gridview ID is "test"

```
    protected void test_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                if(test.SortExpression.Contains( (tc.Controls[0] as LinkButton).Text ))
                    tc.Controls.Add( glyph )
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think the columns collection is set if you are auto generating the columns...

You could check the `Row.Cells.Count` or if you need column names, grab the HeaderRow, and iterate through the Cells & grab their .Text Value.

If the GridView is sortable (e.g. has clickable links in the header, then to get the column names you'll need to check

```
foreach(Row r in GridView.Rows)
{
    if(r.RowType == HeaderRow)
    {
         r.Cells[0].Controls[0]; //Link Control is here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, please see my edit on the question. I actually need the SortExpression property from the column.

Comment: Hello, What should I put in the .Contains()?